# Perl: Find all matched substrings of two strings

Tags: string, perl, comparison, substring, maxlength

Maybe there is a function, which can find every (maximal by length) equal substring of string1 and string2 in perl, isn't it?

I can find every substring in string, using `m/substring/g;`.

For searching all equal substrings, I must shift the pointer of string1's begin and symbol-by-simbol compare strings. How can I do it in perl, or is there a way easer? (the ready function)

Thank you in advance.

`my $string1 = "... (i==i)kn;i=n.n;k(i(i,"%i",&i);i ...";
my  $string2 = "... k;kn;i=n.n;k;k(i(i,"%i",&i);k ...";
my  @answer = ( ..., "kn;i=n.n;", "k(i(i,"%i",&i);", ... );`

Comment: Sounds like a homework...

Comment: The system of plagiarism C-source code checking - checking homeworks, My first program in Perl )))

Comment: show example input and output?  I don't quite get what you are asking for.

Comment: I have added an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example seems to show returning two different lengths of substring, with the shorter one first, so I'm not sure what "maximal by length" means.  But this may help:

```
use Tree::Suffix;
my $string1 = '(i==i)kn;i=n.n;k(i(i,"%i",&i);i';
my $string2 = 'k;kn;i=n.n;k;k(i(i,"%i",&i);k';
my $tree = Tree::Suffix->new($string1, $string2);
my @answer;
my $min_length = 1;
my $max_length = 0; # 0 initially means no limit
do {
    my @by_length = $tree->lcs($min_length,$max_length);
    last unless @by_length;
    # don't include any substrings that are substrings of substrings already found
    for my $new_substring (@by_length) {
        push @answer, $new_substring if 0 == grep $_ =~ /\Q$new_substring/, @answer;
    }
    $max_length = length($by_length[0])-1;
} while $max_length >= $min_length;
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \@answer;
```

output:

```
$VAR1 = [
      ';k(i(i,"%i",&i);',
      'kn;i=n.n;k'
    ];
```

Tree::Suffix was kind of a pain to install; I had to delete the included inc/Devel/CheckLib.pm because it had errors and install Devel::CheckLib separately, as well as downloading and installing the [libstree](http://www.icir.org/christian/libstree/) library.

Comment: Thank you, You have noticed right,  "maximal by length" - "to don't include any substrings that are substrings of substrings already found". What complexity of resulted algorithm is? (using pointers ~ O(n^2)), How much does "tree->lcs" cost?

Comment: I believe it is O(n*m) (the length of the two strings multiplied); I think that is true of any possible lcs algorithm.

Comment: I have the problem while installation Devel::CheckLib using cygwin. It cannot find the standard C libraries, but they are there. This bug must be solved in 1.02, but it is still there. If you have some suggestions in this case, please, make me know. I'm completely stuck. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27025003/while-the-perl-devel-checklib-installation-in-cygwin-make-test-returns-the-er

Comment: Devel::CheckLib is just there to give a nice error message if it can't find libstree installed; you should be able to just skip it by commenting out the use and the check_lib_or_exit call in Tree::Suffix's Makefile.PL.

Comment: Is there another library for perl to construct the suffix-tree? I give up! Because, cpan utility can't install either the origin archive or the archive with changed program, (hashsum is not equal). Package manager of Active Perl don't support this library. And every time cygwin finds the new reason, why it can't be installed.

Comment: there are some other modules to try mentioned here: http://perlmonks.org?node_id=249239